# Jumping to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public void activityStarter(Class<?> cls){
    Intent intent = new Intent( ?, cls);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

What should be passed (see the ? mark) in order start a new activity (another java class I have in the same package, say MyActivity)?

Comment: You have to pass the context of current activity..

Comment: Actually, the program structure demands jumping from one activity to another in several occasions. So I want to create a separate class which can be used to start another activity from different activities.

Answer (score 0):

Context of module from where you are launching this activity, Say if you want it to start from activity A, then pass the Context of Activity A.

Read more about Intents.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

you can also use below, if you dont want to pass any specific module context.

```
public void activityStarter(Class<?> cls){
    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), cls);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the program structure demands jumping from one activity to another in several occasions. So I want to create a separate class which can be used to start another activity from different activities.

Comment: Yes you can create a method inside that class which takes two argument, Context and a Class, use this argument to switch your activity.

Comment: I am using Intellij. It suggests the usage of "Context packageContext". What will be the context in this case? This is my question.

Comment: I dont have much Idea about third party tools for android development, am a native developer. But in this case it means Application Contetx, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void activityStarter(){
    Intent intent = new Intent( from_class.this, to_class.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the child_activity.class as argument. I am using this code to start new activities in multiple occasions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from which activity you want to start new activity just pass context of current activity as CurrentActivity.this

public void activityStarter(Context cntxt){
    Intent intent = new Intent( cntxt, newactivit.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the child_activity.class as argument. I am using this code to start new activities in multiple occasions.

Comment: if you want to create separate class then you have to crate on class which extends activity like below and put the activity calling function in it and simply call it from current activity class

Comment: void activityStarter(Context cntxt, Class<?> cls){
    Intent intent = new Intent( cntxt, cls);
    cntxt.startActivity(intent);
}   you can pass new activity as argument package name.newactivity.class

Answer (score 0):

In any part of your activity code you can call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YOURACTIVITY.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
final String packageName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
final Context context = this;

// call your method like this i.e YourActivity
         private void activityStarter(String dest) {

                  try {
                        Class c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + dest);
                        startActivity(new Intent(context, c));
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), 5000).show();
                    }
           }
```